# slider resize issue using uicomponent and gui layout

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider

I'm using GUI Layout and I have created a `slider` inside a `uicontainer`. All of the functions work except I cannot change the size of the slider. I want it to fill the size of the `uicontainer` (its parent). I do not want to use positions I'd like the slider size to be relative. I have tried setting `MinimumSize` (during creation of the slider and after) and it works but is not enforced on the slider. I've also tried setting '`Height`' and '`Width`' (during creation of the slider and after) and am getting the following error:

```
K>> set(gui.slider, 'Height', 100)
    Error using javahandle_withcallbacks.javax.swing.JSlider/set
    Changing the 'Height' property of javahandle_withcallbacks.javax.swing.JSlider
    is not allowed.

    Error in uicomponent>localSetData (line 720) set(jcomp,propName,propValue);

    Error in uicomponent> @(h,v)localSetData(h,v,jcomp,thisFieldName) 
    (line 249) msp.SetMethod = @(h,v)localSetData(h,v, jcomp,thisFieldName);
```

Could someone tell me how to change the size of the slider? Or if it is impossible and I'm wasting my time trying...

Comment: Is this a vertical or a horizontal slider?

Comment: Yes it was, I found an alternate solution.